# How to prefilled data in form and the form is editable by using react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my react jsx file code overview

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
// and the prefield data which I want to be prefield is commit from API which is 
const nameFromApi = userDatails?.name;

// Here is my function return JSX
<input defaultValue={nameFromApi}  value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize `name` with the value so that will be the initial value of the input

`const [name, setName] = useState(userDatails?.name);`

`<input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are getting a respone from api which is `userDatails` and you want your input to have the value if `userDatails` as its initial value?

You can do something like this

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{

//call your api and get value

...

setName(userDatails?.name)

},[])
```